# Is it possible to install SQL Server on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: package-management

Microsoft documentation always refers to Ubuntu 20.04. We are planning to upgrade to 22.04, but I can't figure out how to install SQL Server there.

When I run command `sudo add-apt-repository "$(wget -qO- https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/22.04/mssql-server-2022.list)"` I get the following error:

> E: The repository 'https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/mssql-server-2022 jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
> N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.

OK, I created a file with `Acquire::AllowInsecureRepositories "1";` in it - and it went few steps forward. It download the packages, but it gave a *different* error:

> Failed to fetch https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/mssql-server-2022/dists/jammy/Release/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 13.93.224.173 443]

It is true, the correct URL is https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/prod/dists/jammy/main/binary-amd64/ - but can I fix it, or this is buried somewhere on Microsoft site?

NOTE: I can't create a tag "sql-server", but the question is about that.

Comment: Short answer is “yes”, but I’ve often run into issues with updates making changes to libraries that SQL Server relies on which breaks the system, usually at the worst time. If you have experience with Docker, [the official containers](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server) have proven to be rock solid 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu 22.04 is not currently supported https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-release-notes-2022?view=sql-server-ver16

But you could install it as a docker container. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72428019/how-to-install-mssql-server-on-ubuntu-22-04