# Can I upgrade Ubuntu if SQL Server installed?

Tags: 20.04, 22.04

I have Ubuntu 20.04 and SQL Server 2019 installed. It is because MS wrote : the SQL Server can be installed on Ubuntu 20.04.
The question is: I see the system message about the new Ubuntu 22.04 available. Upgrade the system?

Can I upgrade Ubuntu 20.04->22.04? Will SQL Server work on it?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1469625/is-it-possible-to-install-sql-server-on-ubuntu-22-04 Seems still valid.

Comment: Yes, it is or it was, but the question: now it works but how will work SQL Server after Ubuntu upgrade to the 22.04

Comment: The release notes state 22.04 is supported in preview. (And I do not know what that means).

Comment: ;-) @Bruni I see, thanx, the question still actual